# Approach plate does not require DME, but DME used in the published missed?

Tags: air-traffic-control, approach, non-precision-approach, missed-approach, precision-approach

[This](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1805/00026IL26L.PDF) approach plate doesn't say "DME REQUIRED", but the published missed approach uses DME.

[image]

Can I still fly it without DME equipment?

If this approach didn't say "RADAR REQUIRED", could you fly it without being in contact with ATC, and how would you manage the DME in the missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DME *can* be used in the published missed, but does not have to be. There are other ways to identify the missed approach fix.

The missed approach instructions are:

> MISSED APPROACH: Climb to 1500 then climbing right turn to 3500 on ATL VORTAC R-005 to TROYS INT/ATL 15 DME and hold.

[image]

The missed approach procedure calls for a hold at the TROYS intersection. This can be identified by one of three means:

1. The intersection of the ATL R-005 and RMG R-115,
2. By 15 DME on the ATL R-005, or
3. By RNAV from a database.

These multiple methods of identification mean that DME is not required. If an RNAV or dual VOR receivers are used, DME is not needed.